# What is the best practice for storing glabal variables of a django App?

Tags: python, django, django-models, model, global-variables

There are a few variables that are unique for my website. For Illustrative purposes let's assume it is a Blog, and the variables I am interested in are the total number of users, the total number of posts, the total number of comments in posts, the average length of a user session, and a few others.

I can create a model with these parameters, and it will have a single row with all the values, but this might be a bit of an overkill. I was wondering if there was a better (pythonic?) way of doing this.

Comment: Actually you would not be overkilling anything, that's the way of doing it. By having a database with those models (User, Post) and performing the appropriate queries you can have that information. You can save some things in cookies, but those things you were speaking about are definitely better if you have them by doing queries.

Comment: The queries sound good to me, the main reason I was asking this question is that I don't want the same query to be run over and over again, so I was wondering how to store the value "Total number of users" after running the query. However, to avoid having that query running over and over given that the numbers increase it actually makes more sense to just use an adequate caching policy.

Comment: Yes, maybe. Good luck, pal. Just as an advice: you should not be worried about doing queries over and over again (as long as they are concise). That's how the internet works, anyway, and your server should be more than prepared to handle that.

Comment: That makes sense, thank you @revliscano!